# Rails capybara test failing due to database_cleaner malfunction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, database-cleaner

I have `database_cleaner` installed and functioning for all my tests except when it encounters this...

```
scenario "is coach, signs up, email not in const, requests admin status" do
  user_sign_in(user1)
  visit my_profile_users_path
  click_button "Request Admin Status"

  expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count).to eq(1)
end
```

Rails returns 
    Failure/Error: expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count).to eq(1)
       expected: 1
            got: 137
       (compared using ==)

Not sure why database cleaner fails on this one instance or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

## Gemfile.rb

```
group :test do
  gem 'coveralls', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy', require: false
end
```

## spec/support/database_cleaner.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.after(:each) do
  end
end
```

## rails_helper.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require_relative "../spec/support/database_cleaner"
```

## spec_helper.rb

```
require 'database_cleaner'
```

Comment: 1) How do you know for sure that it's a problem with `database_cleaner`?  2) Have you tried clearing all deliveries at the beginning of just this spec, to be sure there's not something weird going on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved this by changing the test.

```
scenario "is coach, signs up, email not in const, requests admin status" do
  user_sign_in(user1)
  visit my_profile_users_path
  click_button "Request Admin Status"

  expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.subject).to have_content("#{user1.username} requested admin")
end
```